# How to check folder size or containing files in Java without knowing the file name with java.nio.file?

Tags: java, mirth, java.nio.file

I had a similar question some time ago. Now I don't have any specific file name, because it is a **preprocessor script**. So I need to check the file size of a list of files or the size of a specific path.

the solution with the specific path was:

```js
    var filePath = "//path//to//some//folder//file.name";
    try{
        var fileContent = java.nio.file.Files.size(java.nio.file.Paths.get(filePath));
        var fileSize = fileContent / 1048576;
        logger.debug("Filesize in MB: " + fileSize);
    }
    catch(e){
    ...
```

**what I've already tried:**

```
java.io.File(filePath).length();
```

*here the size doesn't match what's actually in the folder.*

**and**

```
java.nio.file.Files.list(filePath);
```

*here I get a java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head@... which I don't know how to read out in mirth*

Maybe anyone could help or show me another solution to check the a file size before processing without reading in the file on Java Version "1.8.0._92" and Windows Server 2012R2 environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sum the sizes of all files within a directory using streams:

```java
        long total = Files
           .list(Paths.get("c:/some/path/"))
           .mapToLong(p -> p.toFile().length())
           .sum();
        System.out.println(total);
```

**Edit**: The original answer above is in Java. In Mirth javascript it would look like this:

```javascript
        var total = java.nio.file.Files
           .list(java.nio.file.Paths.get("c:/some/path/"))
           .mapToLong(function(p) {return p.toFile().length()})
           .sum();
        channelMap.put('total', total);
```

Comment: this is unfortunately not supported by my current mirth / java version..

Comment: Then you should put your mirth and java version in the original post. If you don't specify, it's generally assumed you are on a current version of mirth and at least java 8.

Comment: @th_lo see edit. This solution will work with at least mirth 3.0+, and probably older as long as you are running at least Java 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
FileChannel fileChannel = FileChannel.open(filePath);
        long fileSize = fileChannel.size();
```

Comment: thanks, that's might be a possible approach. but FileChannel.open will read in the file? if so, that is not a good solution for my case. I want to test big files before processing

Answer (score 0):

found a solution that fits my demands (tested on Mirth 3.4.2.8129) Java Version "1.8.0._92" and Windows Server 2012R2 environment

```
    // Modify the message variable below to pre process data
    var folderPath = "C:////path//to//some//folder";
    var folder = new Packages.java.io.File(folderPath);
    var listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    var count = listOfFiles.length;

    for (i=0; i<count; i++){
        var ext = listOfFiles[i];
        if (ext.toString().endsWith(".name")){ //filter by extentions e.g. .xml
            var file = listOfFiles[i];
            var filestr = file.toString().replace("\\","//"); //adjust for UNC
            var fileSize = java.nio.file.Files.size(java.nio.file.Paths.get(filestr)) / 1048576;
            if (fileSize > 10){
                ChannelUtil.stopChannel(channelId); //stop channel if needed
                throw "File " + file + " is > "+ "10 MB" 
            }
        }
    }
    return message;
```

*If reading from different Server, the Mirth Server (User) must be allowed to read from (UNC) Path*

Comment: Creating a java.io.File on a UNC pathname only works when running java on windows.